# Как определить, что приглашен/удален участник в беседе?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

Здравствуйте. Работаю с `Long-Poll` сервером ВК. Мне необходимо определить, что в беседу был приглашен или из беседы был удален определенный пользователь, я хочу получить его id. Сейчас попробовал приглашать и удалять пользователей, и вот что я получаю в массиве `updates` как при удалении, так и при добавлении участников:

```
[4,ИД_СООБЩЕНИЯ,8225/*флаги*/,ИД_БЕСЕДЫ,1474269459/*время*/,"Имя беседы",""/*сообщение*/],[51/*параметры беседы изменились*/,1,0]
```

Как видно, я получаю пустое сообщение, без всяких намеков на то, что произошло. Ещё и флаги почему-то равны `8225`, хотя такого просто не может быть.

Как можно получить у `Long Poll` сервера, что был приглашен/удален пользователь из беседы и id этого пользователя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Документация у ВК та еще, но...

На самом деле когда приходит код 4 (Добавление нового сообщения) и если **mode** содержит флаг 2, то помимо основных полей в некоторых случаях ответ может содержать дополнительные вложения. Об этом написано тут: https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll_2

В частности сообщение с кодом 4 может содержать не 6, а 7 полей. В 7-ом будет некий экшн (коорый также представлен в таблице [на этой странице](https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll_2)) под именем **source_act** (названия действий) в котором описано:

- chat_create
- chat_title_update
- chat_photo_update
- chat_invite_user
- chat_kick_user

и **source_mid** - идентификатор пользователя, к которому относится сервисное действие

В целом будет выглядеть как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** а на флаги вы просто проверяете сообщение, например если `flag & 2` дал `true` значит это исходящее сообщение. Если `flag & 1` дал `true` то сообщение не прочитано и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался. Я просто делал запрос без `mode=2`. Но всё таки, как могут флаги быть равны `8225`? ведь максимальное число в таблице на странице по вашей ссылке - `512`...

Comment: @LNK честно не помню, но вроде это приходят не те флаги, а общее число прав доступа https://vk.com/dev/permissions в которые, видимо, входят и данные флаги (права).

Answer (score 0):

Каждый флаг представляет собой один бит информации. Для передачи флагов сообщения используется 14 бит, а не 10. По сути это 14 флагов. 1-10 бит для флагов, 11-13 биты видимо резервные и они равны 0, 14-ый бит указывает сообщение из беседы или нет. Вот и получаем если сообщение из беседы, то 14-ый бит будет равен 1 и в десятичной системе счисления число будет больше 2^13 = 8192. Это у них как с id отправителя: больше 2000000000 - конфа, меньше - юзер.